# Java HashSet using a specified method

Tags: java, hash

I have a basic class 'HistoryItem' like so:

```
public class HistoryItem
  private Date startDate;
  private Date endDate;
  private Info info;
  private String details;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = (startDate == null ? 0 : startDate.hashCode());
    hash = hash * 31 + (endDate == null ? 0 : endDate.hashCode());
    return hash;
  }
}
```

I am currently using a HashSet to remove duplicates from an ArrayList on the startDate & endDate fields, which is working correctly.

However I also need to remove duplicates on different fields (info & details).

My question is this.
Is there a way to specify a different method which HashSet will use in place of hashCode()?
Something like this:

```
public int hashCode_2() {
  int hash = (info == null ? 0 : info.hashCode());
  hash = hash * 31 + (details == null ? 0 : details.hashCode());
  return hash;
}

Set<HistoryItem> removeDups = new HashSet<HistoryItem>();
removeDups.setHashMethod(hashCode_2);
```

Or is there another way that I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) for this.

Minimal code change was required.

A new class implementing [TObjectHashingStrategy](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TObjectHashingStrategy.html) (containing `HashCode` and `Equals` methods).

```
public class HistoryItemDuplicateInfo
implements TObjectHashingStrategy<HistoryItem> {

  @Override
  public int computeHashCode(HistoryItem obj) {
     ...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(HistoryItem arg0, HistoryItem arg1) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then use the [THashSet](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/THashSet.html) object with a specified strategy for removing the duplicates.

```
THashSet<HistoryItem> hs = new THashSet<HistoryItem>(new HistoryItemDuplicateInfo());
```

Hope this is able to help someone out in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a wrapper class around `HistoryItem` with a different `GetHashCode` implementation, then make a HashSet of wrappers around each item in the original set.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.  First and foremost, you MUST override equals() if you are going to override hashCode().  This is important.  Second, if you are dealing with different fields, then you should probably have a different HashSet for each field.  So you can iterate over the Map like so:

```
HashSet<String> info;
HashSet<String> details;
for (HistoryItem h:map){
  if(info.contains(h.getInfo()){
    // this is a dup

  }
  if (details.contains(h.getDetails()){
    // this is a dup
  }
  info.add(h.getInfo());
  details.add(h.getDetails());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this code identify all HistoryItems from map which contain either a duplicate info OR a duplicate detail rather than info AND detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the duplicates using a `java.util.TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator` that takes your `Info` and `Details` into account.

Comment: If you use a TreeSet, you will need a TreeSet for each field that you wish to sort on since the comparator is set at construction time.

Comment: This will work, however wouldn't this then require O(n*log(n)) time for n items instead of O(n) for HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you;

- use *long* for a date instead of a Date object.
- use just a Set if you want to avoid duplicates. Why are you using a List at all? If you need to retain a order using a SortedSet like TreeSet or a Set which retains order like LinkedHashSet.
- Can your HistoryItem be valid will null fields? Can you structure your fields so they are never null?
- Fields which make up hashCode/equals/compareTo should be immutable. Can those fields be final? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` is hardcoded to use `hashCode()` and `equals()`. You could implement your own `HashSet`-like class, possibly by ruthlessly duplicating Java's own source code, but that's plain ugly, contradicts any decent set of software development rules, and is possibly illegal with regards to Java's source code license (this depends on the actual JDK, e.g. Sun/Oracle's JDK vs OpenJDK).

You can do things with `TreeSet`, though. `TreeSet` normally uses the `compareTo()` method of the elements, *not* the `hashCode()` or `equals()`. Moreover, a `TreeSet` instance can be built with a custom `Comparator` instance, which is then invoked to do comparisons, making you free to have your own rules. A `compareTo()` method (or a `Comparator.compare()` method) must implement an *order*, which may be a bit trickier than a simple `hashCode()`-and-`equals()`, but this usually not hard either. `TreeSet` is sometimes said to be slower than `HashSet`, but the actual difference is slight and it takes a very specific situation to actually be able to notice that difference in any way.

Conceptually, there could be a hash equivalent of `Comparator` for `HashSet`: an interface `HasherAndEqualizer` with `int hashCode(Object obj)` and `boolean equals(Object obj1, Object obj2)` methods. Sun did not see it fit to include such an interface, I do not know why. Possibly they did not think it would be useful. The "GNU Trove" library that you cite in another answer provides such an interface.

Alternatively, you can always use wrappers. Instead of storing `HistoryItem` instances in your secondary set, you can store `HistoryItemWrapper` instances, each linking to an actual `HistoryItem` and providing the `hashCode()`/`equals()` methods you need for that set.